Struggling to modify a chart title to a specific text, the position of the chart title to be above the chart, and range for chart to work for lastrow?
I have the following VBA application, but I cannot get the chart title to set to cell "B2" text and to position title above chart and then to get the range that is used for the chart to use data up until the last row of different size ranges.
Please see my code application in VBA below. I have been struggling to format and modify this for the past three days. Please help me where possible.
Sub Macro_Histogram_VariableRange()

Macro_Histogram_VariableRange Macro

MsgBox "Histogram being created"
    
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
If Range("F5").Value <> "F" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Range("E6:E402").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(366, xlHistogram).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    AddingAndSettingAChartTitle()

    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "B2"
    
End Sub

That is the first part of my VBA application modification.
The problem is that it gives me a syntax code error ("Can't execute code in break mode"), and the highlights certain things in VBA Application window.
Below is the screenshot.
issue with the sub heading or description. It is highlighted

Where does multiple your text come from in your quesion? Does AddingAndSettingAChartTitle exist in your workbook? I don't think that the brackets are necessary - remove them.

I removed the "your text" since they aren't in the screencap of your code. You appear to be missing an end if. Consider avoiding the use of Select in your code.
